# Confirm a Folder Exists on a Web Server from a C# Desktop Application

Tags: c#, server, directory

I am trying to confirm that a folder has been uploaded to my Website folder so that it can be accessed by a Desktop application.  I keep getting an error that states that there is a URI format error on the connection string.  There is no shortage of 'solutions' on the general internet but I cannot get anything to work, even ones on this site (of which I am a member for many years). Forward slashes, back slashes, no slashes ... on and on.  I am thoroughly confused.  The following seems to be a simple and correct code, but it does not work either even though it is a direct copy of a solution that was offered as correct! The passed string 's' is the name of the folder I am trying to look for. A polite simple answer, perhaps with an example, is my desperate request. Thank You.

```
private bool CheckFiles(string s)
{
    bool exists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(@"\\\\http:/www.myserver.com/sites/"+ s);
    return exists;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`System.IO.Directory.Exists` checks for a directory in the file system. The address that is provided as a parameter is a http-URL that is not supported by file system access.

If you want to check for the presence of the folder on a webserver, you need to use a http client to "talk" to the server. Send a GET or HEAD request to the URL. If this returns a 200 (ok), the folder exists, if it returns 404 (not found), it doesn't.

As you are using .NET Framework 4.5 (or 4.0), you can use WebClient or better HttpClient for this. The following should give you an idea of how to check for the folder:

```
using (var http = new HttpClient())
{
  using (var req = new HttpWebRequest(HttpMethod.Head, "https://..."))
  {
    using (var resp = http.Send(req))
    {
      // This is a very broad condition; 
      // you can also check the StatusCode property against HttpStatusCode.NotFound
      return resp.IsSuccessStatusCode;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just to amplify this: "System.IO.Directory.Exists checks for a directory in the file system"  It checks the LOCAL filesystem.

Comment: Thank you Markus.  I don't know what a head request is. A line of code, such as the one I supplied, that returns a true or false would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Patt what is your technical environment? .NET Core or .NET Framework? Which version?

Comment: Hello Markus, I am using .NET Framework 4.0 or 4.5.  If there is a difference I will get back to you.  Thank you in advance for your assistance.  It came to me that I could order a download to get the information, but all I really need is the file folder name so that I can check that it is present as part of an operational error check.

Comment: By the way (as an aside), the code I supplied was an answer to another person that had an almost identical problem.  It was marked as correct so I copied the solution.  I have no ides why it will not work for ME!!

Comment: A little more information ... these are additional solutions that I have tried:

Comment: //Just so you know, I have also tried all of these.  Not to familiar with LINQ but willing to learn!
}

===

using System.Linq;

private List<FileInfo> GetFilesByMonth(int monthToGet, string directoryPath)
{
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(directoryPath);

    //  note use of the option to search sub-directories
    FileInfo[] theFiles = dir.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    return theFiles.Where(fl => fl.CreationTime.Month == monthToGet).ToList();
}
List<FileInfo> FilesInNovember = GetFilesByMonth(11, @"\\\\server\path");

===